# BASH - Summarising information from several fields in unique field using Loop and If statements

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, awk, multiple-columns

I have the following tab-separated file:

```
A1      A1      0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     2 1     1 1
A2      A2      0       0       2       1       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1
A3      A3      0       0       2       2       1 1     2 2     1 1     1 1     1 1
A5      A5      0       0       2       2       1 1     1 1     1 1     1 2     1 1
```

The idea is to summarise the information between column 7 (included) and the end in a new column that is added at the end of the file.

To do so, these are the rules:

- If the total number of “2”s in the row (between column 7 and the end) is **0**: add “1 1” to the new last column
- If the total number of “2”s in the row (between column 7 and the end) is **1**: add “1 2” to the new last column
- If the total number of “2”s in the row (between column 7 and the end) is **2 or more**: add “2 2” to the new last column

I started to extract the columns I want to work on using the command:

> awk '{for (i = 7; i <= NF; i++) printf $i " "; print ""}' myfile.ped > tmp_myfile.txt

Then I count the number of occurrence in each row using:

> sed 's/[^2]//g' tmp_myfile.txtt | awk '{print NR, length }' >
>   tmp_occurences.txt

Which outputs:

```
1 1
2 0
3 2
4 1
```

Then my idea was to write a for loop that loops through the lines to add the new summary column. 
I was thinking in this kind of *structure*, based on what I found here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples:

```
while read line ;
do
    set $line

    If ["$2"==0]
    then
        $3=="1 1"

    elif ["$2"==1 ]
    then
        $3=="1 2”

    elif ["$2">=2 ]
    then 
        $3==“2 2”

    else
        print ["error"]

    fi
done < tmp_occurences.txt
```

But I am stuck here. Do I have to create the new column before starting the loop? Am I going in the right direction?

Ideally, the final output (after merging the first 6 columns from the initial file and the summary column) would be:

```
A1      A1      0       0       2       1       1 2
A2      A2      0       0       2       1       1 1
A3      A3      0       0       2       2       2 2
A5      A5      0       0       2       2       1 2
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using gnu-awk you can do:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
   c=0;
   for (i=7; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($i==2)
         c++
   if (c==0)
      s="1 1"
   else if (c==1)
      s="1 2"
   else
      s="2 2"
   NF=6
   print $0, s
}' file

A1  A1  0   0   2   1   1 2
A2  A2  0   0   2   1   1 1
A3  A3  0   0   2   2   2 2
A5  A5  0   0   2   2   1 2
```

PS: If not using gnu-awk you can use:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{c=0; for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i==2) c++; $i=""} if (c==0) s="1 1"; else if (c==1) s="1 2"; else s="2 2"; NF=6; print $0, s}' file
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for your quick and elegant answer!

Comment: Nice! Maybe worth saying  `s=2 FS 2` (or OFS) in case the OP wants to keep tabs in between the newly generated columns.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '{match($0,/((\S+\s+){6})(.*)/,a); c=gsub(2,2,a[3]); print a[1] (c>1?2:1), (c>0?2:1)}' file
A1      A1      0       0       2       1       1 2
A2      A2      0       0       2       1       1 1
A3      A3      0       0       2       2       2 2
A5      A5      0       0       2       2       1 2
```

With other awks you'd replace `\S/\s` with `[^[:space:]]/[[:space:]]` and use `substr()` instead of `a[]`.

Answer (score 0):

We can keep the format by using `gensub()` and capturing groups: we capture the 6 first fields and replace with them + the calculated values:

```
awk '{for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i==2)
            twos+=1       # count number of 2's from 7th to last field
        }
      f7=1; f8=0          # set 7th and 8th fields's default value
      if (twos)
          f8=2            # set 8th = 2 if sum is > 0
      if (twos>1)
          f7=2            # set 7th = 2 if sum is > 1
      $0=gensub(/^((\S+\s*){6}).*/,"\\1 " f7 FS f8, 1) # perform the replacement
      twos=0              # reset counter
  }1' file
```

As a one-liner:

```
$ awk '{for (i=7; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i==2) twos+=1} f7=1; f8=0; if (twos) f8=2; if (twos>1) f7=2; $0=gensub(/^((\S+\s*){6}).*/,"\\1 " f7 FS f8,1); twos=0}1' a
A1      A1      0       0       2       1        1 2
A2      A2      0       0       2       1        1 0
A3      A3      0       0       2       2        2 2
A5      A5      0       0       2       2        1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat > test.awk
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                       # for every field
        if(i<7)                                  
            printf "%s%s", $i,OFS              # only output the first 6 
        else a[$i]++                           # count the values of the of the fields
    }
    print (a[2]>1?"2 2":(a[2]==1?"1 2":"1 1")) # output logic
    delete a                                   # reset a for next record
}
$ awk -f test.awk test
A1 A1 0 0 2 1 1 2
A2 A2 0 0 2 1 1 1
A3 A3 0 0 2 2 2 2
A5 A5 0 0 2 2 1 2
```

Borrowing some ideas from @anubhava's solution above:

```
$ cat > another.awk
{
    for(i=7;i<=NF;i++)                             
        a[$i]++                                    # count 2s
    NF=6                                           # truncate $0
    print $0 OFS (a[2]<2?"1 "(a[2]?"2":"1"):"2 2") # print $0 AND 1 AND 1 OR 2 OR 2 AND 2
    delete a                                       # reset a for next record
}
```